Check scaling governor with ansible
I'm changing the scaling governor with Ansible on a host and want to check after reboot with the following ansible play:
  tasks:
  - name: check scaling governor after reboot
    vars:
      scale_gov: "{{ lookup('file', '/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor') }}"
      governor: schedutil
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: scale_gov
    when: governor != scale_gov

The result is always
TASK [check scaling governor after reboot] *******************
ok: [host] => {
    "scale_gov": "powersave"
}

also SSHing into the machine and running cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor echos the previously set governor.
What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug in the file lookup plugin?

After reading the lookup docu again, I read/remembered that lookup('file', path) operates on the control machine, hence it reads the control machines governor setting.
The correct play would be
  tasks:
  - command: cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
    register: scale_gov

  - name: check scaling governor after reboot
    vars:
      governor: schedutil
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: scale_gov
    when: governor != scale_gov.stdout

